# C++ linked list with too many pointers

Tags: c++, linked-list, memory-management

Can someone tell me how I can improve this code? It works ok, but I feel that I'm using too many pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct link{
    int data;
    link *next;
};
class link_list{
private:
    int boundaries = 0;
    link *tail;
    link *temp;
    link *head = NULL;
public:

    void add_node(int data){

        temp = new link;
        temp->data = data;
        temp->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL){
            head = temp;
            boundaries++;
        }
        else{
            link *tail = head;
            while (tail->next != NULL){
                tail = tail->next;
            }
            tail->next = temp;
            boundaries++;
        }
    }
    void delete_b(){
        link *end = head;
        link *next_to_end = NULL;
        while (end->next != NULL){
            next_to_end = end;
            end = end->next;
        }
        next_to_end->next = NULL;
        end = NULL;
        boundaries--;
    }
    void add_front(int data){
        link *ptr = new link;
        ptr->next = head;
        ptr->data = data;
        head = ptr;
        boundaries++;

    }
    void delete_front(){
        link *new_head = head;
        new_head = head->next;
        head = NULL;
        head = new_head;
        boundaries--;

    }


    void add_by_position(int data, int pos){
        link *node = new link;
        link *linker = head;
        node->data = data;
        for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++){
            linker = linker->next;
        }
        node->next = linker;
        linker = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++){
            linker = linker->next;
        }
        linker->next = node;
        boundaries++;

    }

    void show(){
        link *sh = head;
        while (sh){ cout << sh->data << endl; sh = sh->next; }

    }



};


int main()
{
    link_list obj;
    obj.add_node(7);
    obj.add_node(5);

    obj.add_node(8);


    obj.show();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
struct link{
    int data;
    link *next;
};
```

Are you sure you want this to be outside of the class? This could be in the `private` section in the class `link_list` since the outside world does not need to know of this class at all.

---

```
int boundaries = 0;
```

What is `boundaries`? It seems like this is your actual size of the list but I had to check your code to make sure what it is. Call it `size` or `entries` or something like this.

---

```
link *tail;
link *temp;
link *head = NULL;
```

There is no reason to have `temp` as a instance variable. And you do not use `tail` in your code, so drop them both. And use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

---

```
void add_node(int data){

    temp = new link;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL){
        head = temp;
        boundaries++;
    }
    else{
        link *tail = head;
        while (tail->next != NULL){
            tail = tail->next;
        }
        tail->next = temp;
        boundaries++;
    }
}
```

Again, use `nullptr`. And if you had used your `tail` you wouldn't need to iterate over the whole list to get to the end.

---

```
void delete_b(){
    link *end = head;
    link *next_to_end = NULL;
    while (end->next != NULL){
        next_to_end = end;
        end = end->next;
    }
    next_to_end->next = NULL;
    end = NULL;
    boundaries--;
}
```

What's `b`? (Oh yeah, I think I don't need to remind you about `nullptr` again.)

---

```
void add_front(int data){
    link *ptr = new link;
    ptr->next = head;
    ptr->data = data;
    head = ptr;
    boundaries++;

}
```

`add_node` and `add_front`? What's the difference? Sure, I know what the difference is; I've seen the code. However, I don't like to look through the code to see what a function does. Call them `add_front` and `add_back` or something like this (`head` and `tail` might fit better, programmers will understand).

---

```
void delete_front(){
    link *new_head = head;
    new_head = head->next;
    head = NULL;
    head = new_head;
    boundaries--;

}
```

What is this playing around? That's three useless lines of code:

```
void delete_front(){
    link* tmp = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete tmp;
    boundaries--;
}
```

---

```
void add_by_position(int data, int pos){
    link *node = new link;
    link *linker = head;
    node->data = data;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++){
        linker = linker->next;
    }
    node->next = linker;
    linker = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++){
        linker = linker->next;
    }
    linker->next = node;
    boundaries++;

}
```

`by_position` sounds silly. Call it `add_at`. And why do you reset `linker` and start over again? That's totally unnecessary.

```
void add_at(int data, int pos){
    link *node = new link;
    node->data = data;
    boundaries++;
    if(pos == 0) {
      node->next = head;
      head = node;
      return;
    }

    link *linker = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++){
        linker = linker->next;
    }
    node->next = linker->next;
    linker->next = node;
}
```

---

You should also `delete` the nodes in your delete/remove functions.

That's everything for now. You could've easily made a template out of this class, however, you should first fix your problems and then - if you like - ask another question with your new code.